# Python append dictionary item to array in dictionary

Tags: python

What is the proper way to append dictionary value to array of dictionaries?

Original dictionary:

```
dict = {
            "myIPs": [
                    {"IP": "10.0.0.1/32"},
                    {"IP": "10.0.0.2/32"}
                 ]
       }

print dict['myIPs'] -> [{'IP': '10.0.0.1/32'}, {'IP': '10.0.0.2/32'}]
```

Trying:

```
dictarray = dict['myIPs']
dictarray = newdict.append({"IP": "10.0.0.3/32"})

print newdict -> None
```

Comment: Try not to use variable names like `dict`, when they are built-in things (`dict` is the type for dictionaries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the normal way would be:

```
dict['myIPs'].append( {'IP' : '10.0.0.3/32'} )
```

You can access the array object directly via the `dict` handle and it's subsequent key called `myIPs`. This will give you direct access to the array and it's functions. In this case `append()`.

It's quite straight forward once you get used to working with dictionaries.
One way to look at it, is the way you print the array by accessing it via `print dict['myIPs']`, is the same way you'll modify it by accessing it with `dict['myIPs'].append()`. I hope this makes sense.

### [`__builtins__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) - Do not re-use built in functions!

It's a big no-no to re-use system defined/built in functions.
One of which happens to be [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

So please consider changing your variable name to something more appropriate.

```
system_info = {
            "myIPs": [
                    {"IP": "10.0.0.1/32"},
                    {"IP": "10.0.0.2/32"}
                 ]
       }

system_info['myIPs'].append( {'IP' : '10.0.0.3/32'} )
print(system_info['myIPs'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using dict in my code, I changed the parameter names here, but you are correct had to avoid using builtins.

Comment: @DmitryR Glad to hear. I'll still point it out and leave my answer as it is for the next programmer that comes along and copies your code : ) Just so they know what to avoid. Cheers for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
dict['myIPs'].append({"IP": "10.0.0.3/32"})
```